# Error when running pip install -r pip-freeze.txt

Tags: python, pip

I'm setting up RapidPro on my machine. I followed all the steps, but when I run `pip install -r pip-freeze.txt` I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pip-freeze.txt'
```

I checked for this file its not there. Do I have to create the file manually or there is a way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since there is no requirements file called *pip-freeze.txt* in the current working directory, yes, you would have to create that file.

To create the file (with no contents):

```
$ touch pip-freeze.txt
```

You would then have to manually add the project requirements to the file.

Or, to write the install packages (requirements) to a file, whether it has been created or not:

```
$ pip freeze > pip-freeze.txt
```

After either method, to install the listed requirements:

```
$ pip install -r pip-freeze.txt
```